# Can log onto SQL server, but Powershell cannot authenticate

Tags: sql-server, powershell

For over a year, I scheduled a Powershell script to query SQL Server 2008 and output results.

Now I get error

```
"Login failed for user 'sem7'.  Reason: The password of the account has expired."
```

When I reset the password of sem7 to the original password, I am able to log into SQL Server, and other applications that depend on this database are able to pull data from it. However, I still get the same error when running the script.

And when I tried to change the password of sem7 on the SQL server and run PowerShell, I get error

```
"Login failed for user 'sem7'."
```

How do I even troubleshoot this? Is there some permission that needs to be set for sem7 so PowerShell can query it?

Comment: is sem7 a local or domain user?

Comment: @Paul sem7 is local to SQL Server database

Comment: SQL Server doesn't care what is trying to connect (powershell or otherwise). Unless you have a logon trigger that's doing some examination. What is in your SQL error log? You may have a better explanation of what's going on in there.

Comment: @BenThul Thank you, I believe that solved it!